# Disable publishing JOptionPane on application

Tags: java

Greetings everyone. I have a problem which i can solve. I need that JOptionPane does not showing in my application maybe there some way to make this. Best regards Alejandro Del Rio.

Answer (score 1):

Normally a JOptionPane is shown by using one the the showXXX static methods. Using this approach you don't have a reference to the actual dialog so you can't just hide the option pane.

Read the JOptionPane API documentation. There you will find a "Direct Use" example of using a JOptionPane. In this case you are responsible for more code to handle the showing of the dialog and for handling the selected option button. But you do have a reference to the actual dialog so you can use setVisible( false ) as required.

Of course option panes are modal so you still need to somehow schedule the closing of the dialog, maybe by starting a Swing Timer before the option pane is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setVisible() ?

```
JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane();
...
...
...

optionPane.setVisible(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just cant to setVisiable();
I have a class which i does not have a source code and there are many not needed Joptionpane shows i want not one of them is not showing in application.

Comment: This is not an answer. If you have more information about your question then edit your question and add the information.